# JSF and tomcat5 - No Render Response

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, el

There is a developer who wrote a JSF application for my company. He wrote that on tomcat 6 and unfortunately i had to shift everything to tomcat 5. I put a few missing jars and finally was able to perform a request. However in the RenderResponse phase i get the following:

> Jan 29, 2011 8:41:51 PM
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ELResolverInitPhaseListener
>   popu lateFacesELResolverForJsp INFO:
>   JSF1027: [null] The ELResolvers for
>   JSF were not registered with the JSP
>   container. Jan 29, 2011 8:41:54 PM
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl
>   phase WARNING:
>   executePhase(RENDER_RESPONSE
>   6,com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl@c8570c)
>   threw exception
>   com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.ApplicationException:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/JspIdConsumer
>           at com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.faces.ViewHandlerImpl.cleanup(ViewHandlerImpl.java:594)
>           at com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.faces.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:325)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:106)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
>           at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:144)
>           at com.sun.faces.extensions.avatar.lifecycle.PartialTraversalLifecycle.render(PartialTraversalLifecycle.java:106)
>           at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:245)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:875)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/JspIdConsumer
>           at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:413)
>           at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.executePageToBuildView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:439)
>           at com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:114)
>           at com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.faces.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:320)
>           ... 19 more Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/JspIdConsumer
>           at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:273)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:679)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:399)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
>           at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.dispatch(ExternalContextImpl.java:408)
>           ... 22 more Jan 29, 2011 8:41:54 PM
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl
>   phase WARNING: phase(RENDER_RESPONSE
>   6,com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl@c8570c)
>   threw exception:
>   com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.ApplicationException:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/JspIdConsumer
>   javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/JspIdConsumer
>   com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.faces.ViewHandlerImpl.cleanup(ViewHandlerImpl.java:594)
>   com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.faces.ViewHandlerImpl.afterPhase(ViewHandlerImpl.java:470)
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:280)
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:144)
>   com.sun.faces.extensions.avatar.lifecycle.PartialTraversalLifecycle.render(PartialTraversalLifecycle.java:106)
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:245)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:269)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:188)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:172)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:117)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:108)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:174)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:875)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConne
>   ction(Http11BaseProtocol.java:665)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:528)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:81)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:689)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Can someone tell me what this means and how can i solve that? I am researching on this but haven't got a solution yet. Is it because of a wrong version of a jar?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using JSF 1.2, then ensure that you're using Tomcat 5.5 and that your `web.xml` is declared as Servlet 2.4 (and thus not as 2.3 or older with some old fashioned `DOCTYPE`).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <!-- Config here. -->

</web-app>
```

Expression Language (EL) was introduced in JSP 2.0 which is part of Servlet 2.4. The exception indicates that it's declared as Servlet 2.3 or older.

If you're using JSF 1.1, then you should be able to run it on Tomcat 5.0 with a Servlet 2.3 declared `web.xml` (you only need to downgrade JSF 1.2 to JSF 1.1). But if you're using JSF 2.0, then you need Tomcat 6.0 or newer with Servlet 2.5 declared `web.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable inputs but i think i have got the versions correct (by chance :)).My tomcat version is 5.5.27,                                     JSF 1.2.04 (INFO: Initializing Sun's JavaServer Faces implementation (1.2_04-b10-p01) for context 'null') and have this in my web-xml :                                    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
version="2.4">. Please tell me what could be wrong?

Comment: Any chance that the webapp's classpath (`/WEB-INF/lib`, `JRE/lib`, `JRE/lib/ext` and so on) is polluted with old-versioned servletcontainer-specific libraries like `jsp-api.jar` and so on which should be left untouched in servletcontainer's own classpath?

Comment: I have servlet-api and jsp-api in common/lib of tomcat and jstl in my application lib. Changing all that to servlet-api-2.5-6.1.5, jsp-api-2.1-6.0.2 and jstl-1.2 causes my server to never come up :(. Please suggest.

Comment: Oh, you should actually never touch the servletcontainer's own libraries! Whenever you want to do that, then you should in fact be upgrading the whole servletcontainer (e.g. Tomcat 5.5 to 6.0). But that's not needed since JSF 1.2 is supposed to run without issues on Tomcat 5.5. I was just asking whenever you have some servletcontainer specific libraries at places they don't belong. If there are some and they are of a different version, then that would explain the exception you're facing and the solution would be to remove them.

Comment: You need to investigate if the folders `/WEB-INF/lib`, `JRE/lib`, `JRE/lib/ext` do **not** contain any servletcontainer specific libraries such as `jsp-api.jar`, `el-api.jar`, `servlet-api.jar`, etc..etc.. Exactly the ones which you already see in `Tomcat/common/lib`. You should **not** have duplicates of them elsewhere in the classpath. I suggest to undo everything and start clean and then do **not** do "I put a few missing jars", but just report the problem you're facing. Probably you added the wrong JARs or probably it needs to be solved entirely differently.

Comment: ok BalusC - let me clean stuff and get back to you. Thanks again mate.